# Changing input element value in the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a voting system. So when the user clicks the "Vote" button, I want to display the vote count alongside which reflects the count in real time.

I'm using a code something like

HTML

```
<div class='left'>
    <input id='vote' name='voteCount' type='button' value='1' />
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "vote.php",
    data: dataPass,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        $("#vote").val() = count;
    }
});
```

I'm using the input button to display the vote count since I think it's easier for me to get the button value using jQuery `.val()` (which is going to be the vote count at present) then increment it when a user votes it and display the vote count simply by setting the new value as the value of the button.

However, the above codes doesn't seen to work. The value doesn't update after setting it.
So can anyone tell me what's the best way to display the vote count in real time?

Comment: Try debugging some. What if you just try setting the value without the AJAX?

Comment: Can you please give us the important section of your vote.php file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For setting the value the syntax is

```
$("#vote").val(count);
```

Answer (score 3):

There may be other problems, but the jQuery `val()` function expects you to pass the value as an argument, like the following

```
$("#vote").val(count);
```

Instead of

```
$("#vote").val() = count;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the value as an an argument to val:

```
.val(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

`val` method take the new value as argument, you can't assign it like this.
So:

```
$("#vote").val(count);
```

And you'll have to calculate that `count` of course.